# about the instanceof operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I am very new to JavaScript and could not understand the code below (code source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```
// defining constructors
function C(){}
function D(){}

var o = new C();

// true, because: Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === C.prototype
o instanceof C;

// false, because D.prototype is nowhere in o's prototype chain
o instanceof D;

o instanceof Object; // true, because:
C.prototype instanceof Object // true

C.prototype = {};
var o2 = new C();

o2 instanceof C; // true

// false, because C.prototype is nowhere in
// o's prototype chain anymore
o instanceof C;
```

Why in the last line "o instanceof C" returns false? I don't understand how "C.prototype = {}" removes "C.prototype" from o's prototype chain.
thank you!

Comment: C.prototype does indeed replace the entire prototype. If you want to extend prototype chain, just add things onto C.prototype, but don't replace the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

When an object is created, a link to the prototype is placed on the object itself. When the "prototype" property of the constructor is updated, then subsequently-constructed objects will reference that new object, while the old ones still reference the old prototype object. Since that object is no longer associated with the constructor function, the `instanceof` test fails.

The prototype object on the constructor can be *changed* internally as desired without breaking the `instanceof` relationship. That is, properties can be added or removed, and property values can be changed.

In modern JavaScript environments, the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method can be used to retrieve the prototype object of an instantiated object.